# Paired test using GLM with Gamma distribution

Tags: hypothesis-testing, generalized-linear-model, paired-comparisons

I know, that a paired T-test can be formulated in the framework of a linear model for gaussian distributions. I have two vectors of paired mesurements (rates under certain conditions) that follow a Gamma distribution that I want to test for significant difference. I can set it up using a GLM in Matlab to do an unpaired test, but is there a way to do a paired test? It seems, I'm not using all the information in the data if I just do an unpaired test.

Thanks so much!

Comment: you could in principle do this in R (`lme4`) package via: `glmer(y~treatment+(1|pair),family=Gamma(link="log"))` (I would recommend the log link rather than the canonical inverse link for stability.)  Have you considered log-Normal rather than Gamma modeling (i.e., do you have a strong reason to stick to the Gamma distribution)?

Comment: Thanks! Hm, yes, log-Normal might actually work. But anyway, I am very intested to learn the technique. Is an LME model the standard approach in this case? If I were to use a normal famlily in your example, would this be equivalent to a paired T-test?

Comment: yes, `lmer(y~treatment+(1|pair),data=...)` should give identical results to a paired t-test.